# Conflict between code quality check and implicit next() in Express error handling

Tags: node.js, error-handling, software-quality

I am starting with NodeJS. In [error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), the following code declares the `next` callback and does not use it:

```
app.get('/user/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
  var user = await getUserById(req.params.id)
  res.send(user)
})
```

because `next(value)` is implicit from Express 5:

> Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw an error.

This shortcut is in conflict with code quality checks. When I run ESLint on the script, I get:

```
server/app.js
  95:26  error  'next' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
```

What is the appropriate way to get the same functionality and ensure code quality: remove `next` from the function's arguments? Add `next()` at the end? Or disable the rule on code checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are not using next(). so just remove this one.**

```
app.get('/user/:id', async function (req, res) {
  var user = await getUserById(req.params.id);
  res.send(user);`
})
```